# Confusing about the time complexity of DFS in graph

Tags: data-structures, graph

I am evaluating the time complexity of DFS in graph.
I have seen many explanations on the internet, and they all say that the time complexity of DFS is O(e+v), where e is the number of edges and v is the number of vertices.
I have a question: When using DFS, we only visit the vertices, not the edges, so why is the time complexity O(e+v)?

Here is the code I were reading:

```
void help(vector<int>adj[], vector<bool>&freq, int node, vector<int>&dfs){
    if(freq[node]){
        return;
    }
    dfs.push_back(node);
    freq[node] = true;
    for(auto i : adj[node]){
        help(adj, freq, i, dfs);
    }
}
vector<int> dfsOfGraph(int V, vector<int> adj[]) {
    vector<int>dfs;
    vector<bool>freq(V,false);
    help(adj, freq, 0, dfs);
    return dfs;
}
```

Thank you!

Thank you for reading my question, and I hope that you can provide me with the most accurate answer.

Comment: "*we only visit the vertices, not the edges*" - no. You need to go once over each edge to visit a new vertex.

Comment: can you provide me the code line which represents for "go once over each edge"?

Comment: `for(auto i : adj[node])` is iterating through the adjacency list of the node, i.e. over its edges.

Comment: Run this code with a sample graph that has only 2 nodes, but 2**31 edges, all going between those two nodes. I admit, that is a silly graph, but it should get the point across if you run it with that code.